# Chatbot (irc) as WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services, bots

I want to make a IRC bot and got most of the code already, the only thing I don t know yet is or it is possible that I can host it in a WCF service. The problem I think is that it will be garbage collected ??? I want it to run in a WCF service so that I can manage it with my own WPF programm that will consume the WCF service. The bot must be a static object, since I only want the bot to be 1 time made. I don t want multiple instances. Also the bot must be 24/7 online.

Is this possible in a WCF service project ? or should I seperate the project ? in a console app/windows service and a seperate WCF project ?

Maxim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IRC bot doesn't really fit the structure of web services, in my opinion: web services are generally sessionless functions that are in a request/response format, while an IRC bot is something that stays connected to a room and responds to some of the traffic while ignoring other.

A Windows service would probably be my first option. It fits well with what it needs to do: stay open at all times on a server, be able to talk to (messages to/from) the IRC channel as well as a database or other systems (e.g. if you keep a list of banned users in a DB).

Comment: I see, but working with windows services is a pain imo. While WCF is just hosted in the IIS and 1 click to update it straight to the server ! (webdeploy ftw). I am thinking of seperating it. Making a Windows service for the real bot. And it sends everything to the WCF.